# Leetcode 572: subtree of another tree run time and space analysis

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I have question on whether my analysis of runtime and space for algorithm that determine whether a tree **S** contains a subtree that is exactly the same tree as other tree **T** My code is as follows:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if(root == null) return subRoot == null;
        return isSameTree(root, subRoot) || 
            isSubtree(root.left, subRoot) || 
            isSubtree(root.right, subRoot);
        
    }
    
    public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if(root == null) return subRoot == null;
        if(subRoot == null) return false;
        return root.val == subRoot.val && 
            isSameTree(root.left, subRoot.left) && isSameTree(root.right, subRoot.right);
    }
}
```

I think the time is O(S * min(S, T)) where S and T are total number of node of tree s and t respectively, and space is O(max(S, T)). I got the time because we are performing dfs on every node of tree s to determine whether it is the same as tree t, and each dfs takes minimum of node of s and t, and space is because our recursion call stack can at most contain minimum of two tree's node, if smaller tree hits null case while dfsing with larger tree, we will just return

Comment: Seems reasonable. I just wonder if the implementation is correct, because I think it is still the same tree if left and right are switched. So the last line would be isSameTree(root.left, subRoot.left) && isSameTree(root.right, subRoot.right) || isSameTree(root.left, subRoot.right) && isSameTree(root.right, subRoot.left)

Comment: In `isSubtree` you don't need to check for `isSameTree`, you just need to check whether `root` is `subRoot`. Also, you shouldn't perform check on subRoot being null as it is invalid that null is subtree of null. (Null is **not** a subtree of null)

Comment: time complexity analysis seems correct.

Comment: The analysis seems correct but it can be done in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check on subRoot being null as it is invalid that null is subtree of null. So, in that case you can return false. Please use this code for your reference and time
complexity  O(mn), where m = |nodes| ∈ root and  n = |nodes| ∈ subRoot

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isSubtree(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if(root == null) 
            return false;
        if (isSameTree(root, subRoot))
            return true;
        return isSubtree(root.left, subRoot) || isSubtree(root.right, subRoot);
    }
    
    public boolean isSameTree(TreeNode root, TreeNode subRoot) {
        if(root==null || subRoot==null)
            return root==subRoot;
        return root.val == subRoot.val && isSameTree(root.left, subRoot.left) && isSameTree(root.right, subRoot.right);
      
        
    }
}
```